# Hibernate: why join on intermediate table without mappedBy in @OneToMany?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a hierarchy `Employee ==> Department`:

```
@Table(name = "EMPL")
class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPAR", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Department department;
}

@Table(name = "DEPAR")
class Department {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

Without `mappedBy = "department"` in `@OneToMany` I get join on non-existing table, from log:

```
/* delete collection com.evil.entity.Department.employees */ delete 
    from
        DEPAR_EMPL
    where
        DEPAR_ID=?
```

or:

```
select ...
from
    DEPAR_EMPL employees_ 
inner join
    EMPL emplx1_ 
        on employees_.lvl2s_ID=emplx1_.ID 
inner join
    DEPAR deparx2_ 
        on emplx1_.LVL1=deparx2_.ID 
where
    employees_.DEPAR_ID=?
```

Why Hibernate generate queries with non-existing table *DEPAR_EMPL* which named as concatenation of my table names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you don't specify `mappedBy`, the OneToMany association is not the inverse side of the ManyToOne association anymore. It thus becomes a completely different association, and since you didn't specify how this new association is mapped, the default mapping for a OneToMany unidirectional is assumed: a join table named the way you're seeing it.

Comment: Are there any way to mark association as inverse without `mappedBy`? Theoretical question...

Comment: No. That's what mappedBy is for.